# get current path Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, routes

I've tried to find the full path of current route in `Laravel 5.x`

For this case i've created a method with the following code, but i can't imagine that `Laravel` does not provide something like this themselves:

```
 $current = Route::getFacadeRoot()->current();
 $uri = $current->uri();
 foreach ($current->parameters() as $key => $param) {
     $uri = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $param, $uri);
 }
 return url($uri);
```

Is there something out of the box in `Laravel` that i just can't find?

Answer (score 5):

you can use

```
Request::url()
```

blade:

```
{{\Request::url()}} // if is in blade
```

Comment: Thanks, this was my solution..

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;` and you need an instance of `Request`. the url added by @martin-bean explains how

Answer (score 4):

Try this clause:

```
URL::current();
```

Or:

```
$request->url();
```

Or PHP way:

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```

Answer (score 3):

Laravel has a handy method on the `Request` class, coincidentally, called `fullUrl()`:

```
Request::fullUrl();
```

This is covered in the Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/master/requests#accessing-the-request

Comment: Yep, that's working! Thanks `Request::fullUrl();` does also pass the `GET request` parameters which i just don't need. In that case the answer of @kscorrales is working for my own situation.